# About golfing, Is there a nice way to not have redundancy in this code?

Tags: go

I just started learning golang. In a structure, I am using the below:

```
type Sell struct {
    Pair string      `json:"pair"`
    OrderType string `json:"order_type"`
    Amount string    `json:"amount"`
}

type Buy struct {
    Pair string      `json:"pair"`
    OrderType string `json:"order_type"`
    Amount string    `json:"buy_amount"`
}

func CreateSomething(a, b, c, OrderType string) {
    SellPram := Sell{}
    BuyPram  := Buy{}
    if OrderType == "sell" {
        SellPram = Sell{a,b,c}
        json.Marshal(SellPram)
    } else if OrderType == "buy" {
        BuyPram = Buy{a,b,c}
        json.Marshal(BuyPram)
    }
}
```

In this code, I declared structures in main function both `SellPram` and `BuyPram`, but I think this is very redundant in the code. 
So is there a nice way to not declare both `SellPram` and `BuyPram`.
I don't want to declare both of them, because at least one side will not use by the end of the function.

Comment: why you have created 2 different structs with the same fields ?

Comment: Last json factor is not same, Sell is the last one is amount, but Buy is the buy_amount. this needs to post the website as deference field.

Answer (score 0):

You may move common part to a separate structure and then embed it into the structures:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Order struct {
    Pair      string `json:"pair"`
    OrderType string `json:"order_type"`
}

type Sell struct {
    Order
    Amount string `json:"amount"`
}

type Buy struct {
    Order
    Amount string `json:"buy_amount"`
}

func CreateSomething(a, b, c, OrderType string) {
    SellPram := Sell{}
    BuyPram := Buy{}
    if OrderType == "sell" {
        SellPram = Sell{Order{Pair: a, OrderType: b}, c}
        s, err := json.Marshal(SellPram)
        fmt.Println(s, err)
    } else if OrderType == "buy" {
        BuyPram = Buy{Order{a, b}, c}
        s, err := json.Marshal(BuyPram)
        fmt.Println(string(s), err)
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    CreateSomething("a", "b", "c", "buy")
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/aTjSRkMVqr